# Who was the first to capitalize Real?

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, kt.k-theory-and-homology

For example in Atiyah's $KR$-theory there is the notion of a *Real vector bundle* in contrast to complex or real vector bundles. I am also familiar with the notion of a Real $C^*$-algebra and there are probably a lot more objects with sensible definitions of *Real*.

However Atiyah did not use a capitalized *Real* in his paper "K-theory and reality", so my question is:

> Whose ideas was it to write *Real* instead of *real*?

I would also be interested in the general history of this notion, but that's probably too much to ask for (judging from remarks in the above mentioned paper I suspect it starts somewhere in algebraic geometry – of which I hardly know anything.)

Comment: Is there any reason to think that it was *not* Atiyah in the article mentioned?

Comment: I had never heard this terminology before, but it seems like an atrocious idea for a number of reasons to distinguish "real" and "Real" (how are you supposed to make the distinction orally? how are you supposed to start a sentence with "Real vector bundles"? and — of course this problem might have been unforeseeable when the term was invented — how are you supposed to search for this online? or simply, look it up in an encyclopedia?).

Comment: Surely it would be better to write "complexified vector bundle" rather than "Real vector bundle".

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, there is also the distinction in motivic integration between 'function' and 'Function'.  (I agree about its desireability!)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen When I'm discussing KR-theory with my advisor (in German) we usually say "real" instead of the German word "reell" to make the distinction … that's bearable, though a poor choice still

Comment: @Gro-Tsen my suggestion would be to speak it as if it were a quote following a colon **:"Real"** which could be emphasized visually by finger wiggling

Comment: This reminds me of Bill Thurston's story about how, before he came up with the terminology "orbifold", he tried other terms. One of those was "manifolded". This led to conversations like "No, not manifold, manifolDEAD".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently, Atiyah himself thinks he invented the notation:

[image]

(quote from his [collected works](https://books.google.nl/books?id=XHnWhjQZpkUC&pg=PA620&lpg=PA620&dq=Real+vector+bundle+with+capital+R&source=bl&ots=Ay51I5tFlY&sig=5Qilhujr56C8TtXuMNC0nchzrS8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW8_mH1L7aAhUPzqQKHQZKBMIQ6AEIUDAD#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Comment: So, er, "5. The Real case" or "5. The real case"..?